# Steering behaviors: Why is my wandering algorithm not working as intended?

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine

We're learning about steering behaviors in my artificial intelligence for games class, and I figured I'd try my hand at implementing some of them. I've mainly been reading [The Nature of Code](https://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-6-autonomous-agents/) to familiarize myself with the topics.

[Here](https://github.com/AleksandrHovhannisyan/SteeringBehavior) is the repository for my Unity project. The relevant scene is under `Assets/Scenes/Wandering.unity`.

Here's the associated script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Wandering : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxSpeed;
    private float speed;
    public float maxForce;
    public float radius;
    private Rigidbody body;


    void Awake()
    {
        body = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        speed = maxSpeed;
        body.velocity = new Vector3(5, 0, 5);
    }


    void Update()
    {
        // Get future position
        Vector3 futurePosition = GetFuturePosition();

        // Select random point on circle of radius "radius" around the future position
        Vector3 target = GeneratePointOnCircle(futurePosition);

        // Compute desired velocity as one pointing there
        Vector3 desiredVelocity = GetDesiredVelocity(target);

        // Get the steering force vector
        Vector3 steerForce = desiredVelocity - body.velocity;
        steerForce.y = 0;

        // Cap the force that can be applied (lower max force = more difficult to turn)
        if (Vector3.Magnitude(steerForce) > maxForce)
        {
            steerForce = Vector3.Normalize(steerForce) * maxForce;
        }

        // Apply the force to the body
        body.AddForce(steerForce);
    }


    /* Returns a random point on a circle positioned at the given center and radius.
     */ 
    Vector3 GeneratePointOnCircle(Vector3 center)
    {
        Vector3 point = center;

        float angle = Random.Range(0, 360) * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
        point.x += radius * Mathf.Cos(angle);
        point.z += radius * Mathf.Sin(angle);

        return point;
    }


    /* Computes and returns the future, predicted position of this object, assuming
     * it continues traveling in its current direction at its current speed.
     */
    Vector3 GetFuturePosition()
    {
        // We have a current velocity
        // We have a time elapsed
        // We have a current position
        // Future position = current position + current velocity * delta time

        return transform.position + body.velocity * Time.deltaTime;
    }


    /* The desired velocity is simply the unit vector in the direction of the target
     * scaled by the speed of the object.
     */
    Vector3 GetDesiredVelocity(Vector3 target)
    {
        return Vector3.Normalize(target - transform.position) * speed;
    }
}
```

Values set in the editor:

- `maxSpeed`: 40
- `maxForce`: 20
- `radius`: 60

When I run this, the agent does not behave as intended. The main problem is that instead of traveling smoothly, it stutters around in brief bursts, seems to pause, and then starts moving again. This random behavior is still pretty neat, and sort of mimics that of a disoriented rodent, but I'm looking for more intelligent-seeming behavior.

Is there a flaw in my script or logic that's forcing the agent to behave in this erratic manner? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh, I think I may have figured it out. Does it have to do with the fact that `Time.deltaTime` is such a small value, and therefore providing a very tiny prediction into the future? It's technically the time elapsed since the last frame, which as I understand is always constant.

Comment: I suppose I should also create a random initial velocity, because otherwise I bias the general direction the agent heads in.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem was my use of `Time.deltaTime` for calculating the predicted point in the future if the agent were to continue at its current velocity.

Since this is really the time elapsed since the last frame update, it's quite a small number. Thus, using it for predicting the future point was misleading and would produce points very close to the agent (hence the "stuttering" behavior).

Instead, I opted to use a fixed "lookahead" time (say `2`) to predict further into the future.